# VLC streaming using command line

Tags: streaming, mp3, vlc

I am trying to stream an mp3 file using VLC command line and play/open it in browser. What I am looking for is a guide or a detailed how-to.
I've looked at the samples here:
[http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples#HTTP_streaming](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aStreaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples#HTTP_streaming)
However none of the samples work for me and there is very little information/explanation on the page.